# Testing a component that uses a service to get some data

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a service that reads some data from the store and then based on that data returns a boolean Observable. It is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

   enabledObv$: Observable<any>;

   constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
      enabledObv$ = this.store.select<any>(‘some-store’);
   }

   checkIfExists$(someData: any): Observable<boolean> {

   return this.enabledObv$.map(
       (dataClass: any) => {
           return _.includes(dataClass.someField, someData);
       });
   }

}
```

Now, this service is being used in a component. Specifically, I am using the `checkIfExists$` method against some values that I have in my component.

On running the tests I am getting the error:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { rootReducer } from '../../../../store/root-reducer';
import { SomeComponent } from ‘./some.component';
import { SomeService } from '../../../../shared/services/config/some.service';

describe(‘SomeComponent’, () => {
    let component: SomeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [SomeComponent],
        imports: [// modules that the component is using],
        providers: [SomeService]
    }).compileComponents();

    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();

    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

As suggested, adding the component code:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    ifExistsA$: Observable<boolean>;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor(private someService: SomeService, private store: Store<AppState>) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initAEnabled();
    }

     private initAEnabled(): void {
        this.ifExistsA$ =
            this.someService.checkIfExists$(valueToBeChecked);
     }

}
```

Now the ifExistsA$ is used in the HTML file with the async pipe to show something. The access is like: ifExistsA$ | async

Essentially I am using `ifExistsA$` to show some data, depending on its presence in the store.

On running this test I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataClass' of undefined
```

Where am I going wrong?
Do I have to do something with the service other than adding it as a provider?
Do I have to mock it?
If I have to mock it, do I have to provide some value for the `dataClass`?
If so then how do I do that?

Comment: Can you please add minimal component code of `SomeComponent`.

Comment: @AmitChigadani on it

Comment: @AmitChigadani check now, I've added.

Comment: Are you sure your app is working fine? Because you are not subscribing to `checkIfExists$` in your component like `this.ifExistsA$ =
            this.someService.checkIfExists$(valueToBeChecked).subscribe();`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your service is the problem. You are providing the real service to the testing component but it's not getting instantiated correctly which is why the method fails.

You can do one of the following:

1. Create a stub service that has a stub implementation of the public methods, then providing that to the component test in place of the real service. It'll look something like `providers: [ {provide: SomeService, useValue: new StubService()}]`
2. In your beforeEach block spy on `checkIfExists$` so the real implementation doesn't get called.

It'll look something like:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { rootReducer } from '../../../../store/root-reducer';
import { SomeComponent } from ‘./some.component';
import { SomeService } from '../../../../shared/services/config/some.service';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
    let component: SomeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;
    let service: SomeService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [SomeComponent],
        imports: [],
        providers: [SomeService]
    }).compileComponents();

    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        service = TestBed.get(SomeService);
        spyOn(service, 'checkIfExists$');
        fixture.detectChanges();

    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I hope that helps.